# XSLT Select node if parents don't have matching children

Tags: xslt, xpath, unique, tablerow

I have a source exerpt of xml:

```
        <TableRow TableRowLevel="1" RowTitle="" TableRowNumber="2" class="OddLegacy">
            <TableCell>
                <Paragraph>10.140.50.50</Paragraph></TableCell>
            <TableCell>
                <Paragraph>Sun Solaris 8</Paragraph></TableCell>
            <TableCell>
                <Paragraph>53.1</Paragraph></TableCell>
            <TableCell>
                <UnorderedList UnorderedListLevel="1" class="compactList" UnorderedListNumber="1">
                    <ListItem>opusone.dal.veritas.com</ListItem>
                    <ListItem>OPUSONE</ListItem></UnorderedList></TableCell></TableRow>
        <TableRow TableRowLevel="1" RowTitle="" TableRowNumber="3" class="Even">
            <TableCell>
                <Paragraph>10.140.50.163</Paragraph></TableCell>
            <TableCell>
                <Paragraph>Sun Solaris 8</Paragraph></TableCell>
            <TableCell>
                <Paragraph>53.0</Paragraph></TableCell>
            <TableCell>
                <UnorderedList UnorderedListLevel="1" class="compactList" UnorderedListNumber="1">
                    <ListItem>dns1.dal.veritas.com</ListItem>
                    <ListItem>opusone.dal.veritas.com</ListItem></UnorderedList></TableCell></TableRow>
        <TableRow TableRowLevel="1" RowTitle="" TableRowNumber="4" class="OddLegacy">
            <TableCell>
                <Paragraph>10.140.50.82</Paragraph></TableCell>
            <TableCell>
                <Paragraph>HP-UX 870849686</Paragraph></TableCell>
            <TableCell>
                <Paragraph>31.4</Paragraph></TableCell>
            <TableCell>
                <UnorderedList UnorderedListLevel="1" class="compactList" UnorderedListNumber="1">
                    <ListItem>unknown</ListItem>
                    <ListItem>testarossa.dal.veritas.com</ListItem></UnorderedList></TableCell></TableRow>
        <TableRow TableRowLevel="1" RowTitle="" TableRowNumber="5" class="Even">
            <TableCell>
                <Paragraph>10.140.50.71</Paragraph></TableCell>
            <TableCell>
                <Paragraph>Microsoft Windows Server 2008 R2, Enterprise Edition</Paragraph></TableCell>
            <TableCell>
                <Paragraph>30.5</Paragraph></TableCell>
            <TableCell>
                <UnorderedList UnorderedListLevel="1" class="compactList" UnorderedListNumber="1">
                    <ListItem>EVSERV1.evexample.local</ListItem>
                    <ListItem>EVSERV1</ListItem></UnorderedList></TableCell></TableRow>
```

I need to output a table row for each row in the source if the OS (Microsoft Windows Server 2008 R2, Enterprise Edition) is unique.
So far I have:

```
                <xsl:for-each select="Table/TableRow[TableCell[2]/Paragraph[not(preceding-sibling::TableCell[2]/Paragraph)]]">

                    <xsl:sort select="TableCell[2]/Paragraph"/>
                        <xsl:variable name="newosname" select="TableCell[2]/Paragraph"/>
                        <xsl:variable name="oscount" select="count(parent::Table/TableRow[TableCell/Paragraph = $newosname])"/>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <xsl:value-of select="$newosname"/>
                                <xsl:value-of select ="TableCell[2]/Paragraph[not(preceding::TableCell[2]/Paragraph)]"/>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <xsl:value-of select="$oscount"/>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                </xsl:for-each>
```

Note the preceding not test is just me playing with trying to test the axis'.

Expected output

```
<tr>
<td>Sun Solaris 8</td>
<td>2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>HP-UX 870849686</td>
<td>1</td>
</tr>
....
```

Answer (score 0):

The following template:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" exclude-result-prefixes="xs">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:variable name="oss" as="xs:string+">
            <xsl:sequence select="distinct-values( Table/TableRow/TableCell[2]/Paragraph/text() )"/>
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:variable name="table" select="Table/TableRow"/>
        <xsl:for-each select="$oss">
            <xsl:sort select="."/>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <xsl:value-of select="count($table[TableCell[2]/Paragraph/text() = current()])"/>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

applied to the provided input XML gives the following output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<tr>
    <td>HP-UX 870849686</td>
    <td>1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Microsoft Windows Server 2008 R2, Enterprise Edition</td>
    <td>1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Sun Solaris 8</td>
    <td>2</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: I didn't know you want XSLT-1.0 :( I developed and tested this code in XMLSpy and it worked.

Comment: Sorry I tried using v2 in the stylesheet but still broken in the browser (firefox 5)

Answer (score 0):

**This XSLT 1.0 transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:key name="kRowByOs" match="TableRow"
  use="TableCell[2]/Paragraph"/>

 <xsl:template match=
  "TableRow
     [generate-id()
     =
      generate-id(key('kRowByOs', TableCell[2]/Paragraph)[1])
     ]">
  <tr>
   <td><xsl:value-of select="TableCell[2]/Paragraph"/></td>
   <td><xsl:value-of select=
    "count(key('kRowByOs', TableCell[2]/Paragraph))"/></td>
  </tr>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="text()"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the following XML document** (the provided fragment wrapped into a single top element):

```
<t>
            <TableRow TableRowLevel="1" RowTitle="" TableRowNumber="2" class="OddLegacy">
                <TableCell>
                    <Paragraph>10.140.50.50</Paragraph></TableCell>
                <TableCell>
                    <Paragraph>Sun Solaris 8</Paragraph></TableCell>
                <TableCell>
                    <Paragraph>53.1</Paragraph></TableCell>
                <TableCell>
                    <UnorderedList UnorderedListLevel="1" class="compactList" UnorderedListNumber="1">
                        <ListItem>opusone.dal.veritas.com</ListItem>
                        <ListItem>OPUSONE</ListItem></UnorderedList></TableCell></TableRow>
            <TableRow TableRowLevel="1" RowTitle="" TableRowNumber="3" class="Even">
                <TableCell>
                    <Paragraph>10.140.50.163</Paragraph></TableCell>
                <TableCell>
                    <Paragraph>Sun Solaris 8</Paragraph></TableCell>
                <TableCell>
                    <Paragraph>53.0</Paragraph></TableCell>
                <TableCell>
                    <UnorderedList UnorderedListLevel="1" class="compactList" UnorderedListNumber="1">
                        <ListItem>dns1.dal.veritas.com</ListItem>
                        <ListItem>opusone.dal.veritas.com</ListItem></UnorderedList></TableCell></TableRow>
            <TableRow TableRowLevel="1" RowTitle="" TableRowNumber="4" class="OddLegacy">
                <TableCell>
                    <Paragraph>10.140.50.82</Paragraph></TableCell>
                <TableCell>
                    <Paragraph>HP-UX 870849686</Paragraph></TableCell>
                <TableCell>
                    <Paragraph>31.4</Paragraph></TableCell>
                <TableCell>
                    <UnorderedList UnorderedListLevel="1" class="compactList" UnorderedListNumber="1">
                        <ListItem>unknown</ListItem>
                        <ListItem>testarossa.dal.veritas.com</ListItem></UnorderedList></TableCell></TableRow>
            <TableRow TableRowLevel="1" RowTitle="" TableRowNumber="5" class="Even">
                <TableCell>
                    <Paragraph>10.140.50.71</Paragraph></TableCell>
                <TableCell>
                    <Paragraph>Microsoft Windows Server 2008 R2, Enterprise Edition</Paragraph></TableCell>
                <TableCell>
                    <Paragraph>30.5</Paragraph></TableCell>
                <TableCell>
                    <UnorderedList UnorderedListLevel="1" class="compactList" UnorderedListNumber="1">
                        <ListItem>EVSERV1.evexample.local</ListItem>
                        <ListItem>EVSERV1</ListItem></UnorderedList></TableCell></TableRow>
</t>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result:**

```
<tr>
   <td>Sun Solaris 8</td>
   <td>2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
   <td>HP-UX 870849686</td>
   <td>1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
   <td>Microsoft Windows Server 2008 R2, Enterprise Edition</td>
   <td>1</td>
</tr>
```

**Explanation**:

Proper use of the **[Muenchian method for grouping](http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html)**.